# Android - Prevent delay when using windowShowWallpaper

Tags: android, performance

I want the phone wallpaper in my app but it causes a delay when opening the app, I see the app icon for about 300ms to 500ms, only then the wallpaper appear.
When I use a solid color, I see that color instantly, but not with the wallpaper.
I'm currently using in the styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
```

and also tried in onCreate():

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable background_image = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
appContainerView.setBackground(background_image);
```

and in styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

but I'm still with delay opening the app.
Is there any other method or flag that speeds up this process?